# 404 error showing 'Cannot GET /' for docker container with nodeJS+Express application

Tags: node.js, docker, express, routes

I get a 404 error in the browser on locahost:4001 after starting a docker container running a nodejs application.

dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

ARG NODE_VERSION=18.14.0

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production \
    DB_CONNECT=...

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=package-lock.json,target=package-lock.json \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm ci --omit=dev

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4001

CMD node server.js
```

I use the command docker build -t test to build the container, then docker run -it p 4001:4001 test to run the container. Server is running but browser shows only: 'Cannot GET /'.

I containerized another nodejs application following the instructions and using the repo from [instructions on docs.docker](https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/containerize/) and that works fine but I can't make my own nodejs app up and running.

I checked with command docker exec -it  /bin/sh that all files of the app are copied correctly into the image. If I run node server.js the script runs fine (telling that port address 4001 is already in use). Furthermore the favicon is shown correctly, the html title shows 'Error' instead of the name in the  tag of the index.html page:

[image: error in browser]

Running localhost:4001/get-lid (one of the endpoints in server.js) works fine however:

[image: endpoint get-lid]

Running the app locally outside a docker container works just fine:
[image: nodocker]

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

const { DB_USER, DB_PASS, DEV, DB_CONNECT } = process.env
// console.log("user: ",DB_USER," pass: ",DB_PASS," dev: ",DEV," connect: ",DB_CONNECT)
// const dbAddress = '127.0.0.1:27017'
const dbName = 'wkb_db'
const collName = 'leden'

// const url = DEV ? `mongodb://${dbAddress}` : `mongodb://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@${dbAddress}?authSource=${dbName}`
const url = `${DB_CONNECT}`
// console.log("url: ",url)
const client = new MongoClient(url)
// console.log("client: ",client)


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/dist'))

app.get('/get-lid', async function(req, res) {
    
    // connect to mongodb database
    await client.connect()
    console.log('Connected successfully to server')

    // initiate or get the db & collection
    const db = client.db(dbName)
    const collection = db.collection(collName)
    
    // get data from database
    const result = await collection.findOne({id: 1})
    console.log(result)
    client.close()
    
    response = {}
    if (result !== null) {
        response = {
            lidsinds: result.lidsinds,
            achternaam: result.achternaam,
            voornaam: result.voornaam,
            adres: result.adres,
            postcode: result.postcode,
            woonplaats: result.woonplaats,
            geboortdedatum: result.geboortedatum,
            email: result.email,
            club: result.club,
            licentie: result.licantie
        }
    }
    res.send(response)
    
})

app.post('/update-lid', async function(req, res) {
    
    const payload = req.body
    console.log(payload)    
    if (Object.keys(payload).length === 0) {
        res.send({error: "Geen informatie ontvangen. Gegevens van lid zijn niet gewijzigd"})
    } else {
        // connect to mongodb database
        await client.connect()
        console.log('Connected successfully to database server')

        // initiate or get the db & collection
        const db = client.db(dbName)
        const collection = db.collection(collName)

        // save payload data to the database
        payload['id'] = 1;
        const updatedValues = { $set: payload }
        await collection.updateOne({id: 1}, updatedValues, {upsert: true});
        client.close()
        
        res.send({info: "Gegevens van lid zijn gewijzgd"})
    }
})

app.listen(4001, function () {
    console.log("app listening on port 4001")
})
```

Any ideas what is wrong? I guess it has to do with routing
`app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/dist'))`
but I don't understand why it only doesnt work inside the docker container and works fine outside the container.

Edit:
I found a way to display the static content (client-side) however then the server-side doesn't work:

Install Nginx inside the Docker container, instructions at the bottom of page [Vue CLI Deployment guidelines](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html)

Replacing dockerfile with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

with nginx.conf file with for me only the port set to 4001 instead of 80:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make client side and server side work?